# TCP IP Communication

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

I have made a client program using boost::asio in C++ which connects to a TCP/IP server. When I send a command say "llist" it will return

```
? "llist"
l1 32x32 Video "Video L1"
l2 512x512 Video "Audio L2"
```

Each sentence end by a new line character and at end of the transmission it will have an extra new line character. So my listening function reads two characters from the socket

```
 len=_socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(reply,sizeof(reply)),error);// char reply[2];
```

The problem is when I check for "\n" using if it doesn't work.

```
  if(reply[0]!='\n')
    if(reply[1]!='\n')
       str.insert(i,1,reply[0]); //std::string str;
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: I can try to infer your logic, but I would have to make some potentially inaccurate assumptions. You are reading from the socket 2 characters at a time, checking for newlines. Since you clear 2 characters with your conditionals you would have to insert both the 0 and 1 index of reply. It appears that you are only inserting the first. Is this the behavior you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given much details of what's going wrong, but at a guess, your current way of reading will drop valid characters (ie. what's in `reply[1]`).

You can instead use [`boost::asio::read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html) to read an entire line :

```
boost::asio::read_until(socket, buffer, '\n');
```

and treat an empty line as the end of the transmission.